# Node, express как создать модель без подключения БД

Tags: node.js, express

Как создать модель к примеру Book без подключения базы данных? Во всех гайдах используется база данных, мне нужно просто сделать модель проверить как идет запрос и вернуть json. Альтернативой БД будет объект или массив.

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, вы хотите проверить как идет запрос к базе данных без создания базы данных? Или вы хотите, чтоб на сервере лежал json-файл и вы при запросе его отдавали?

Comment: А что именно вы понимаете под моделью?

Comment: Я уже понял, что на момент написания вопроса я по сути сам не понимал что спрашиваю. Меня немного вводит в ступор js после java где мне все очевидно, есть модели, контроллеры, интерфейсы, сервисы. А тут как то, как в голову пришло. Вопрос мой уже не актуален массив или объект создается как обычно.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен просто большой массив для каких-то тестов то можно скачать например на гите https://github.com/dwyl/english-words файл *words.txt*

```
var DATA = fs.readFileSync("./words.txt", "utf8").split("\n");
```

и будет массив 270+ тысяч слов.
Если нужен JSON то можно так-же найти большой JSON и загрузить его похожим образом

```
 var JSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./filename.json"));
```